# Removing Pulseaudio installs Pulseaudio

Tags: 16.04, apt, sound, pulseaudio

I'm trying to debug a broken sound system on an Ubuntu 16 laptop.

I want to try completely uninstalling Pulseaudio, so I ran:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge pulseaudio
```

However, this generates the odd output:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  indicator-sound* pulseaudio* pulseaudio-module-x11* pulseaudio-utils* rtkit* unity-control-center*
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gcc-5-base:i386 gcc-6-base:i386 gnome-control-center libasound2:i386 libasound2-plugins:i386 libasyncns0:i386 libaudit1:i386 libc6:i386 libcap2:i386 libdbus-1-3:i386 libfftw3-single3:i386 libflac8:i386
  libgcc1:i386 libgcrypt20:i386 libgomp1:i386 libgpg-error0:i386 libice6:i386 libjack-jackd2-0:i386 libjson-c2:i386 libltdl7:i386 liblzma5:i386 libogg0:i386 liborc-0.4-0:i386 libpam-systemd:i386 libpam0g:i386
  libpcre3:i386 libpulse0:i386 libpulsedsp:i386 libsamplerate0:i386 libselinux1:i386 libsm6:i386 libsndfile1:i386 libspeexdsp1:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libsystemd0:i386 libtdb1:i386 libudev1:i386 libuuid1:i386
  libvorbis0a:i386 libvorbisenc2:i386 libwebrtc-audio-processing-0:i386 libwrap0:i386 libx11-6:i386 libx11-xcb1:i386 libxau6:i386 libxcb1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386 libxext6:i386 libxtst6:i386 **pulseaudio:i386**
  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth pulseaudio-module-x11:i386 pulseaudio-utils:i386 rtkit:i386
```

It looks like it's going to install the pulseaudio:i386 package, even though I'm explicitly telling it to remove the pulseaudio package. What's going on here?

Comment: what happens if you just do a `sudo apt update` \ `sudo apt upgrade`? I'm trying to see if all this change traffic is generated by what you're doing, or if you have unincorporated updates.  I'm particularly intrigued by the `gcc` part.

Comment: That shows nothing needs updating/upgrading.

Comment: Did you have an luck?